# Modulator Small Signal Transfer Function

Tags: buck

[image]

How is the transfer function derived from that figure?

Comment: What book?  What does it say in the text near the figure?

Comment: Check slide 28 of my [APEC 2013](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202014.pdf) seminar for more details.